# Flow of execution- mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My query in MySQL looks like this:

```
    SELECT *, min(start_date_time) as min_start_date_time
    FROM result_table
    where part_number= '101'
    group by part_serial;
```

I was expecting that the query will group the results by `part_serial` and then will create a new column `'min_start_date_time'` that has the minimum `start_date_time` in each row, for a given `part_serial`.

But what I am getting is, a only 1 row for each `part serial`, where the `start_date_time` is the minimum for the given `serial`.

Can someone explain the flow of execution for this query?

Comment: `group by part_serial` creates one group per `part_serial` value. The result you get is one row per group.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  That will help us figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: *"the minimum start_date_time in each row, for a given part_serial."* sounds just like *"1 row for each part serial, where the start_date_time is the minimum for the given serial"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from creating boundaries for aggregate function calculations, it sounds like you were expecting the GROUP BY clause to act more like an ORDER BY clause, simply forcing rows in a group next to each other in the results. This is not the case. The GROUP BY clause will actually filter a result set down to one row per group.

> Can someone explain the flow of execution for this query

I'll take a stab at it, but keep in mind that this is a very simplified flow. It doesn't take much to get a lot more complicated than this, and the database can use statistics and indexes to change this basic query flow when the query engine thinks it can produce a faster or more efficient plan. I also can't leave it to just this query, as explaining the process flow without giving at least a tip of the hat to JOINs and other complexities creates some misleading interpretations. That disclaimer out of the way, let's get to it.

The process begins with a planning phase to identify the table-space. That is, the database computes the table used by the FROM clause along with the matching rules for tables or views in any JOINs. It does not actually load any of this into memory, aside from perhaps record pointers or a primary key. Right now it's just computing matching rules for tables and determining the most efficient way to complete the joins and build the resulting rows.

As an example, you may join to a table with 5 columns where the join condition matches on a foreign key in the third column, but the table's primary key is the first column and the select list ultimately only uses the data from the fourth column. At this stage, the database is just building the plan for the fastest way to load that fourth column data for each record with your original table. There may be an index with columns 3 and 4 it can use to satisfy the query, or it may need to load data from the original table via the primary key in column 1. Making that kind of decision is what's involved here.

For a single-table query like with this question, all this is usually just a matter of determining whether or not the query can be fully satisfied from an index, but it's still an important part of the process.

When that is done, the database starts examining rows in the query's main/original table. The database will apply relevant parts of the WHERE clause first (hopefully making good use of an index), to keep the working set small. Then it pulls in data for any joined tables that match the rules determined in the previous step. It applies any remaining elements of the WHERE clause as it does this, hopefully making use of a helpful index on the joined tables... again, to keep the query's memory and disk use as low as possible and get unnecessary information released as quickly as possible.

Sometimes this process will materialize new rows, when, say, a join matches more than one record in the target table, but the process continues until the entire results for an originating row are computed.

As each materialized row is finalized, the GROUP BY clause can be applied. This works by looking at the row and identifying to which group the row belongs. At this point, the row is merged (not copied) into a new working set (this can be skipped if there is no GROUP BY clause). If the new set already has a row that matches the group, then it just updates any aggregate function computations (add 1 to COUNT for that group, check if we have a new MAX or MIN, update a SUM that will eventually allow an AVG computation, etc). If the new set does not already have a row for that group, a row is created in the set with seed data from the current row. As the database finishes rows from the original set they can be discarded. Once the entire GROUP BY clause is done the original working set is no longer needed for the query.

At this point, the HAVING clause (if any) can be evaluated, as well as the ORDER BY clause.

Finally, the the database starts streaming results to the client application. As each row is streamed, any transformations specified by the SELECT clause are executed and included with the final result set. Note if you don't have a GROUP BY, ORDER BY clause, DISTINCT, or windowing function, the streaming can begin as soon as the *first* record is ready. If you have any these things, the entire result set must be built in order to know how to do the streaming, which can't begin until the *last* record is ready. This can be *huge* for performance both in terms of initial latency and resource use on the server.